# Is there a way to have Prettier ignore a block of code (etc, a huge list) in python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, prettier

I'm using VSCode for a project, and I have created a big list to store some data. I want to keep it in a block and tidy, but Prettier keeps changing it into an odd format and makes it hard to read for me. I've tried to use `# prettier-ignore` and `# prettier-ignore-start <list> # prettier-ignore-end` but nothing works.

Comment: It seems that this is not a problem with vscode or python. You can describe your problem in more detail on GitHub. https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues